# error with strpos on form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding the locations for groups, and the user can search based on the location to find the nearest group to them. The fields are: country, state, city, neighborhood. Let's say there are ten groups in the USA -- I don't want it to list the option USA ten times. I added in a strpos so that it will only list them once, but I'm getting an error.

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
$myQuery = "select country, state, city, neighborhood from groups WHERE group_status = 'open to new members'";

$rs = mysql_query($myQuery);

$country_options = $state_options = $city_options = $neighborhood_options = '';

while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){

$pos_country = strpos($get_row['country'], $country_options);

if($pos_country === false) {
echo $country_options .= "<option value='" . $get_row['country'] . "'>" . $get_row['country'] . "</option>";}

$pos_state = strpos($get_row['state'], $state_options);
if($pos_state === false) {
echo $state_options .= "<option value='" . $get_row['state'] . "'>" . $get_row['state'] . "</option>";}

$pos_city = strpos($get_row['city'], $city_options);
if($pos_city === false) {
echo $city_options .= "<option value='" . $get_row['city'] . "'>" . $get_row['city'] . "</option>";}

$pos_neighborhood = strpos($get_row['neighborhood'], $neighborhood_options);
if($pos_neighborhood === false) {
echo $neighborhood_options .= "<option value='" . $get_row['neighborhood'] . "'>" . $get_row['neighborhood'] . "</option>";}

}
?>
```

It outputs the following errors:

> Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in sidebar.php on line 66
>
> Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in sidebar.php on line 70
>
> Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in sidebar.php on line 73
>
> Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in sidebar.php on line 76

Underneath the error it has a nice form with the correct fields: country, state, city, neighborhood. It's just listing the same countries multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `delimiter` for `strpos()` is the second parameter passed in.

In your code, you start out with:

```
$country_options = $state_options = $city_options = $neighborhood_options = '';
```

These are each the values you use as delimiters, and they are all empty - hence your error. *After* you perform your `strpos()` checks using a given key, *then* you set it. For instance:

```
$pos_country = strpos($get_row['country'], $country_options);
if($pos_country === false) {
    echo $country_options .= "<option value='" . $get_row['country'] . "'>" . $get_row['country'] . "</option>";
}
```

I'm not sure what character you're searching for with `$country_options`, but you immediately append a `<option></option>` tag to it (which is one really long delimiter). Are you, perhaps, using the wrong variables as the characters you're searching for?

**EDIT**
After re-reading your question, I understand the goal you're trying to achieve (I think). You simply don't want to display the same country, state, city, or neighborhood more than once.

To accomplish this, it may be easier to keep an array of "seen" values and just check that array in each loop. Try something like this:

```
$countries = array();
$states = array();
$cities = array();
$neighborhoods = array();

while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    if (!in_array($get_row['country'], $countries)) {
        $country_options .= '<option value="' . $get_row['country'] . '">' . $get_row['country'] . '</option>';
        $countries[] = $get_row['country'];
    }

    if (!in_array($get_row['state'], $states)) {
        $state_options .= '<option value="' . $get_row['state'] . '">' . $get_row['state'] . '</option>';
        $states[] = $get_row['state'];
    }

    if (!in_array($get_row['city'], $cities)) {
        $city_options .= '<option value="' . $get_row['city'] . '">' . $get_row['city'] . '</option>';
        $cities[] = $get_row['city'];
    }

    if (!in_array($get_row['neighborhood'], $neighborhoods)) {
        $neighborhood_options .= '<option value="' . $get_row['neighborhood'] . '">' . $get_row['neighborhood'] . '</option>';
        $neighborhoods[] = $get_row['neighborhood'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I was amidst suggesting using arrays instead of and saw your edit. +1

Comment: Ok, great! We're getting somewhere. Thanks! Now it's only showing the country option once, which is great.

Now I'm getting this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: country_options in sidebar.phpon line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: state_options in sidebar.phpon line 92

Notice: Undefined variable: city_options in sidebar.phpon line 97

Notice: Undefined variable: neighborhood_options in sidebar.phpon line 102

Comment: If the data is sorted you just need to store the _last seen value_. It should be sorted, by country, state, city etc.